# Convolution2D TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'subsample')

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm using InceptionV4 from [here](https://github.com/systemcorp-ai/InceptionV4/blob/master/inceptionv4.py)

but I got this error message

```
def conv_block(x, nb_filter, nb_row, nb_col, border_mode='same', subsample=(1, 1), bias=False):
    x = Convolution2D(nb_filter, nb_row, nb_col, subsample=subsample, border_mode=border_mode, bias=bias)(x)


TypeError
('Keyword argument not understood:', 'subsample')
  File "C:\Labbb\inception\InceptionV4-master\inceptionv4.py", line 84, in conv_block
    x = Convolution2D(nb_filter, nb_row, nb_col, subsample=subsample, border_mode=border_mode, bias=bias)(x)
  File "C:\Labbb\inception\InceptionV4-master\inceptionv4.py", line 97, in inception_stem
    x = conv_block(input, 32, 3, 3, subsample=(2, 2), border_mode='valid')
  File "C:\Labbb\inception\InceptionV4-master\inceptionv4.py", line 230, in create_inception_v4
    x = inception_stem(init)
  File "C:\Labbb\inception\InceptionV4-master\inceptionv4.py", line 269, in <module>
    model = create_inception_v4(load_weights=check)
TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'subsample')
```

I tried use "strides" instead of "subsample", but got another erroe message

```
def conv_block(x, nb_filter, nb_row, nb_col, border_mode='same', subsample=(1, 1), bias=False):
    x = Convolution2D(nb_filter, nb_row, nb_col, strides=subsample, border_mode=border_mode, bias=bias)(x)

TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'strides'
```

Comment: Inception V4 is available in Keras applications here: https://keras.io/api/applications/inceptionresnetv2/ No idea why you are trying to implement it using 4 year old code that requires a lot of updates just to make it run.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy your link is InceptionResnetV2, I haven't seen that Keras 2 supports InceptionV4, or I should to use InceptionResnetV2 is better than InceptionV4?

Comment: Look carefully at the reference in the link, it is to the InceptionV4 paper, which is actually, InceptionResnetV2, they are the same network.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Thank you, I will go to try more new version code

Answer (score 0):

I thought the code is right,may the method be used have renewed in any version,So try to check if the version you install is correct , I look through the project **requirements.txt**.
The related package:

```
Keras==2.2.4
Keras-Applications==1.0.8
Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.0
```

use

```
pip list
```